# How does YouTube do its "live streaming" comments on videos?

Tags: php, javascript

Example: if you go to a video on YouTube.com and click "Show comments in real time" (or something like that), the comments start to show in real time. How do they do this and how would I be able to efficiently duplicate this feature (preferrably using PHP and JavaScript)?

Thanks!

Comment: I've been wondering about the same thing. I think it uses some sort of clever Flash-code mixed with Javascript and Ajax. I am not sure how the pull out the current timestamp from the video, and I am pretty sure you can't do it with javascript alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean what I think you mean, and it's similar to the way facebook will load comments on posts etc 'as soon' as they are posted, then it's using AJAX to load the new comments, and Javascript and PHP to create a new HTML element with the comment in it. To my knowledge there is no real way of making this happen other than to continuously look for new comment, but it could be a JavaScript to look for a new comment every 10 seconds, or every time an event fires....

Comment: It would also be possible with WebSockets, i.e. whenever someone posts a comment, the server immediately sends the data to other clients who are on the same page. I'm not sure if YouTube does that, though.

Comment: Oh wow! WebSockets are very interesting! I'd never come across them before. Now I have some interesting reading for this morning, thanks!